# Issues with installing and using Vue-Social

Tags: vue.js, npm, vite

I was trying to import [Vue-Socials](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-socials) into my project so I could use social media logos.

However, even when I've downloaded the package through npm multiple times, it's throwing me this error:

```
Internal server error: Failed to resolve entry for package "vue-socials".
The package may have incorrect main/module/exports specified in its package.json: Failed to resolve entry for package "vue-socials".
The package may have incorrect main/module/exports specified in its package.json.
```

I tried to look around in the package.json, but I understood nothing (I could attach the package.json of the library here and I might possibly need to).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That error occurs when one of the package's entries points to a non-existent file (as seen in this [Vite issue](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/7754)).

Looking at `vue-socials`'s `package.json`, notice the [`browser` entry is `./dist/vue-socials.esm.js`](https://github.com/webistomin/vue-socials/blob/ea5b6d14b9ac5e44e2ebcb43a3f0530d48aef9c5/package.json#L21), but the file under `dist` is actually named [`vue-socials.es.js`](https://unpkg.com/browse/vue-socials@2.0.0-0/dist/) (without the `m`).

A workaround is to alias `vue-socials` to the correct path:

```js
// vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'

export default defineConfig({
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue-socials': 'vue-socials/dist/vue-socials.es.js', 
    },
  },
})
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-vue-socials?file=vite.config.js)

Comment: As a hotfix for anyone who don't want to mess with the config, just import it straight from path, BUT remember it will fail if the names changes under dist/